# Azure AD SAML Custom Login Page

Tags: php, azure, symfony, saml-2.0, simplesamlphp

I'm currently integrating Azure AD SAML non gallery application to my website.

I'm using Azure AD as Identity Provider
Then, my website as Service Provider

And i'm using Symfony Bundle called "LightSAML SP-Bundle"

The normal flow is, once you want to login, you will redirected to Outlook/Microsoft login page.
Is it possible to use own/custom login page instead of using the default by the Microsoft login?

Thank you.

Comment: It is _technically_ possible, but seriously not recommended. If you want users to be able to use multi-factor authentication, they must use the Microsoft login page. Federated accounts most of the time also need to use the MS login page. If their password has expired, they can change it to a new one only at the MS login page as well.

Comment: @juunas - Would this be possible without SAML, or in any way? That is, validating with username/password against Azure AD AND use MS's MFA as they do in their interactive flow?